# PowerShell: What is the equivalent of the path enviromental variable

Tags: powershell

What is the equivalent of the path enviromental variable in PowerShell? I want to automatically include msbuild.exe when I start the console.

Comment: Oh dear, what ever are you talking about?

Comment: We could play this game forever!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the PATH environment variable using `$env:PATH`.